# Windows 8 Log In After Remote Desktop Session Slow

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

I often log into my Windows 8 machine remotely when I am out of the office.  When I return to the machine and try to log in locally the system often sits for a few minutes with a black screen before it resumes.  I can see three white dots that appear to be the Metro UI sidebar separator, so it looks as if the Metro UI might have trouble swtiching between a remote and local sessions.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and know of any work arounds to speed up reconnecting after remote desktop?

Comment: I have noticed this too :\